# How to remove carriage returns in a text editor?

Tags: text-editor, text, notepadqq

How can I go about remove carriage returns from a file in a text editor?

For example, if I start with this:

```
Hello
world
this
is
an
example
```

I'd like to end up with:

```
Hello world this is an example
```

---

How do I do this in Text Editor and Notepadqq in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is easy to do in Ubuntu's default text editor [gedit](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/gedit) a.k.a. **Text Editor**.

Open Find and Replace menu by using the default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> key shortcut or by using the context menu in the top right of gedit.

1. If you are editing a file with UNIX-style line endings, do a find & replace like so:

   Find: \n
   Replace with: space

   [image: Find and Replace dialog box, searching for Unix-style (LF) line endings]

---

2. If you are editing a file with Windows-style line-endings, do a find & replace like so:

   Find: \r\n
   Replace with: space

   [image: Find and Replace dialog box, searching for Windows-style (CRLF) line endings]

Comment: @EliahKagan even if it doesn't work in Notepadqq, OP could still copy/paste into gedit... *shrug*

Comment: I believe the OP may have been interested in how to do it in multiple editors, based on the original wording in the question--that's why I was asking. (In some desktop environments, gedit appears in menus as "Text Editor.") This answer is definitely valuable.  I've added a heading so people know this is gedit. @HidekiNishimura I've edited your question to make it say what I think you had intended. But if that is not correct, please feel free to roll back my edit or otherwise edit again.